# pie chart using jFreechart and add the chart in pdf in iText

Tags: pdf, itext, jfreechart, pie-chart

Error occurs when in try { } I just want it to work. Complete with the jars used for jfree and itext. Please help :(

```
package com.pieChart.sample;


import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.orsonpdf.DefaultFontMapper;

public class PieChart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        writeChartToPDF(generateBarChart(), 500, 400, "C://barchart.pdf");
        writeChartToPDF(generatePieChart(), 500, 400, "C://piechart.pdf");
    }

    public static JFreeChart generatePieChart() {
        DefaultPieDataset dataSet = new DefaultPieDataset();
        dataSet.setValue("China", 19.64);
        dataSet.setValue("India", 17.3);
        dataSet.setValue("United States", 4.54);
        dataSet.setValue("Indonesia", 3.4);
        dataSet.setValue("Brazil", 2.83);
        dataSet.setValue("Pakistan", 2.48);
        dataSet.setValue("Bangladesh", 2.38);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
                "World Population by countries", dataSet, true, true, false);

        return chart;
    }

    public static JFreeChart generateBarChart() {
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataSet.setValue(791, "Population", "1750 AD");
        dataSet.setValue(978, "Population", "1800 AD");
        dataSet.setValue(1262, "Population", "1850 AD");
        dataSet.setValue(1650, "Population", "1900 AD");
        dataSet.setValue(2519, "Population", "1950 AD");
        dataSet.setValue(6070, "Population", "2000 AD");

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                "World Population growth", "Year", "Population in millions",
                dataSet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);

        return chart;
    }

    public static void writeChartToPDF(JFreeChart chart, int width, int height, String fileName) {
        PdfWriter writer = null;

        Document document = new Document(null);

        try {
            writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                    fileName));
            document.open();
            PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
            PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(width, height);
            Graphics2D graphics2d = template.createGraphics(width, height,
                    new DefaultFontMapper());
            Rectangle2D rectangle2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width,
                    height);

            chart.draw(graphics2d, rectangle2d);

            graphics2d.dispose();
            contentByte.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        document.close();
   }
}
```

Errors at Try {}
1.PdfWriter
2.PdfContentByte
3.PdfTemplate
4.Graphics2D
5.Default Font Mapper
6.Rectangle2D
all of those errors say "cannot be resolved" or "cannot be resolved to a type"

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    PdfWriter cannot be resolved to a type
    Document cannot be resolved to a type
    Document cannot be resolved to a type
    PdfWriter cannot be resolved
    FileOutputStream cannot be resolved to a type
    PdfContentByte cannot be resolved to a type
    PdfTemplate cannot be resolved to a type
    Graphics2D cannot be resolved to a type
    DefaultFontMapper cannot be resolved to a type
    Rectangle2D cannot be resolved to a type
    Rectangle2D cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Are there any jar files missing in the code to be error-free?

Comment: *"Error occurs when in try { }"* - **which error?** You print the stacktrace, simply add it to your question.

Comment: _"if I did that, most likely a new error would occur."_ What happens when you try?

Comment: Why is the parameter of the `Document` constructor `null`? Which exception is thrown? Is it a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Considering your edits you get compile time errors, not runtime errors... looking closer at your code you import some itext 7 classes but try to use them as if they were itext 5.x classes. Itext 7 is a complete rewrite of the library, so that won't work. But the error "FileOutputStream cannot be resolved to a type" shows that you have problems even with normal jre classes. Thus, you should consider starting the project from scratch.

Comment: In addition to what mkl already wrote: please use Maven, and show us your pom.xml. I am not interested in jars you downloaded because I don't know if you have them in the classpath.